# how to write into a single file (create from stream class) from two different files using ofstream

Tags: c++, ios, fstream, ofstream

I am using ofstream to write into a file.

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("test.txt",ios::app);
```

Now, I want this variable "myfile" to be used by two different files.
eg:example.cc and example1.cc

I have declared 'myfile' in example.cc file, and after a function call when the call goes to example1.cc, I am using the same name 'myfile ' to write into the same file test.txt.
But I am getting error as

```
#example1.cc 'myfile' was not declared in the scope
```

I know that its not in scope, But as I am new to cpp , I don't know how to make a same file available to two different file.

If I declare a file in example1.cc than it will become a new file rite?

Comment: You have not provided enough code to know what's up but I am going to hazard a guess. Try adding `#include <fstream>` at the top and putting `std::` in front of when you use it like: `std::ofstream myfile;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I have finally understood what you are trying to achieve. You want to have access to one stream from two different source files(translation units). I assume that due to the fact that you are new to C++, I should suggest the simplest solution. Please do not assume that it is the best one, as it has a lot of caveats. We have project that contains three source files: `foo1.cpp`, `foo2.cpp`, `main.cpp`:

File foo1.cpp

```
#include <fstream>

extern std::ofstream logger;

void foo1()
{
    logger << "Foo1 started" << std::endl;
    //some stuff
    logger << "Foo1 finished" << std::endl;
}
```

File foo2.cpp

```
#include <fstream>

extern std::ofstream logger;

void foo2()
{
    logger << "Foo2 started" << std::endl;
    //some stuff
    logger << "Foo2 finished" << std::endl;
}
```

File main.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

std::ofstream logger;

void foo1();
void foo2();

int main()
{
    logger.open("./data.txt", std::ios::app);

    foo1();
    foo2();

    logger.close();
}
```

This code would hope fully compile and after execution there will be a file `data.txt` with this content:
    Foo1 started
    Foo1 finished
    Foo2 started
    Foo2 finished

I think that the most interesting for you should be the fourth line from `main.cpp` and third lines in `foo1.cpp` and `foo2.cpp`.

The fourth line in `main.cpp`, because the logger is declared outside `main` function, this allows other function to reach the logger and use it. This is true not only for the functions in this `.cpp` file. The compiler will put the address to this variable in symbol table for `.o` file, and this is exactly what was my intention. You may try to add `static` keyword before it and see what will happen. (it will disable this behavior)

Third lines from `foo1.cpp` and `foo2.cpp` informs the compiler that there will be such a variable(it will now now its name and type) in the symbol table of some `.o`(`main.o` in our case). The compiler will generate the code that uses such a variable and will place in the symbol table that this file need such variable to be provided(aka. undefined symbol).

If you manage to understand this you may also use your own header file. There is some kind of duplication in this "project". The first three lines of `foo1.cpp` and `foo2.cpp` are exactly the same. You may want to use header file to reduce this.

logger.hpp:

```
#include <fstream>

extern std::ofstream logger;
```

foo1.cpp:

```
#include "logger.hpp"

void foo1()
{
...
```

foo2.cpp

```
#include "logger.hpp"

void foo2()
{
...
```

The headers files are usually used just for this, to keep the interface to other source files in one place, additionally to in-line function and templates. If you will ever think to use it for something else, please think again

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked...I am so happy. Thanks for this informative post. :)